# Website Domains in Azure

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke

I have deployed a installation of DNN in Azure and registered custom domain CNAME to point at the DNN install and the sites which are registered in the CMS; however azure is reporting the site is not present?

can anyone help please?

Comment: Can you access the site (DNN) using the *.azurewebsites.net URL?  I just want to confirm that the site is functional.

Comment: yes, the site is fully functional under the azurewebsites.net URL

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need to configure the custom domain name in Azure.

See section [Point your Domain Names at Azure Websites](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/154972/launching-a-dnn-microsoft-azure-website)

You may need to upgrade your DNN installation from FREE to Shared (or higher) in the Azure portal before you can manage the domain.  This is explained in the above link.

And here's official info on adding custom domains to Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/